# How do I make Ubuntu recognize my WiFi network card?

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

First of all I have to say I am using Ubuntu and Linux at all for a day now... so sorry if I ask dumb questions.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to get a wireless connection. In *All Settings* > *Network* I see only *Wired* and *Network proxy*, so I guess Ubuntu does not recognize any wireless card or at least does not have the right drivers to use it properly.

My PC is a HP Compaq Presario C500. Here is some information from the terminal:

`lshw -class network`:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:80400000-80403fff
[...]
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

`lspci`:

```
06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
```

`rfkill list all`:

```
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: You're almost there. You've identified your WiFi adapter. It's a very common Broadcom BCM4311 device, which is not supported very well. [Search for BCM4311](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=BCM4311) and you'll find tons of ways to get it working. Have you tried the application "Hardware Drivers"? It should suggest the installation of the driver.

Comment: The "Additional Drivers" program has been moved to "Software Sources" found under the edit menu of the Software Center.

Comment: bcm4311 can be found in the "Additional Drivers" and "it is using alternative driver", but, nope... still nothing appears under wireless netowrks in Edit Connections...

Comment: [No reproducible](http://askubuntu.com/questions/232146/how-do-i-make-ubuntu-recognize-my-wifi-network-card/416594#comment287074_232180)

Answer (score 1):

first uninstall `bcmwl-kernel-source` and then make sure `firmware-b43-installer` and `b43-fwcutter` are installed

> `sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source`
>   `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter`

Comment: I tried it several times, tried some other things I found here searching for solution... Unfortunately no luck... I guess I will go back to the old Windows and just wait for a working driver here.

Thanks for the help, guys! Keep doing what u r doing! :)

Answer (score 0):

After doing this:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
```

- Then Reboot
- And you need to activate the card from settings/network/wireless make it ON
- After this search for wireless icon at the task bar and look for your wifi.

happy surfing :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Ubee! There's already another answer that mentions the same steps. So instead of posting the same answer again, you can up-vote it by clicking on the little up arrow to the left of the answer. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) to [upvote answers](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/vote-up). If you think an answer can be a little bit improved, you can suggest an edit to it by clicking the `edit` link right underneath the text of the answer. Thanks!